# How can i add multiple textures to my THREE.JS object?

Tags: image, object, three.js, load, textures

i try to add seven images (textures) to my object, but it doesn't work

```
    let loaderCar = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    var car;
    loaderCar.load('/Cars/E30/scene.gltf', function (gltf) {
        car = gltf.scene;
        car.traverse(function (node) {
            if (node.isMesh)
                for (i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
                    node.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: textureLoader.load('/Cars/E30/textures1/' + i + '.png') })
                }

        });
        scene.add(gltf.scene);
    });


    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
    animate();
```

My object is still black..
[image: object_black]

It should be like this
[image: how_it_should_be]
Thanks!

Comment: Phong material needs lights to be illuminated. Have you added lights to your scene? Also, have you checked your developer console to see if there are any image loading issues?

Comment: ^This, and also `texture.flipY = false` is required when adding textures to glTF models.

Comment: @Marquizzo, no loading issues. How can i add lights? Don McCurdy, where to put this code?